# Programming Pattern - Single Data Structure - Multiple Methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a single data structure that holds a relatively small amount of objects (ca. 1500) and several methods that are acting on it. Is there a programming pattern to iterate the methods over the data instead of writing significantly more boilerplate code?

Comment: [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) allows you to work on collections while abstracting the boilerplate code. I suggest you to read [this article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/refactoring-pipelines.html) by Martin Fowler (some of his examples are in C#).

Comment: Do the methods all have the same parameters and return values? Or does the result of one method get sent to the next? Example code could help.

Comment: The methods have all the same parameters and return values

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819062/programming-pattern-single-data-structure-multiple-methods

Comment: A little more information about your use case would be helpful. Please see [how to ask a good question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP violated the "no crossposts" policy of the SE network blatantly, and the corresponding question on Stackoverflow got already some good answers. Moreover, the question is hard to understand without an example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think there is a design pattern for this. It's much too simple to be a pattern, I believe.

You have a list of objects and a list of functions, and you want the cartesian product of those two lists, e.g.

```
objects := [10, 20, 30]
functions := [add1, subtract1]

product := functions.product(objects)
// product looks like this:
// [(add1, 10), (subtract1, 10), (add1, 20), (subtract1, 20), (add1, 30), (subtract1, 30)]

product.map((fn, o) => fn(o))
// => [11, 9, 21, 19, 31, 29]
```

In C#, it would look a bit like this (I don't really know C#, so take it with a grain of salt):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Prog
{
    static int add1(int i) => i + 1;
    static int sub1(int i) => i - 1;

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var objs = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30 };
        var funs = new List<Func<int, int>> { add1, sub1 };

        var result = 
            from obj in objs 
            from fun in funs 
            select fun(obj);

        result.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        // 11
        // 9
        // 21
        // 19
        // 31
        // 29
    }
}
```

Comment: add1/sub1 would be more like `static int add1(int i) { return i + 1 }` or `static Func<int, int> add1 = i => i + 1;`

Comment: Why? The OP explicitly talked about methods, your second suggestion is a field, not a method. And your first suggestion is exactly what I wrote, only more verbose.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman That is a new C# 6.0 syntax.

Comment: @svick Oh. Jörg W Mittag: My bad. I thought you made a mistake since you said you didn't know C# well. I haven't use this new fangled syntax yet.